# Android 4.0 Calendar API Get Events For Specific Calendar

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-calendar

I can query for all the calendars and I can query for all events. How do I tie the two together to filter events based on chosen calendar?

Also, is there also a way to query for just recent events (like last 10 events globally)?